# Should I link these parts of the hasse diagram?

Tags: relations

Where X divides by Y on the set A = {1,2,3,6,10,15,30}

The answer I've been given in this example was:

```
                 30
               /  | \
              10  6  15
                  |\
                  2 3
                  |
                  1
```

Why doesn't the 2 link to the 10 or the 3 link to the 15? Was the example answer I was given wrong, or is there some reason for these not to be joined?

Comment: The answer is wrong, and you should also link $1$ to $3$.

Comment: So it should also have 2 to 10, 3 to 15, and 1 to 3?

Comment: Yes, thats right

Comment: You should have a link from $a$ to $b$ whenever $a|b$ and there isn't some $c\neq a$ and $c\neq b$ with $a|c|b$.